# Python interpreter path search order on windows

Tags: python, path, interpreter

Many applications include a python interpreter, so now when I try to run a program, Subversion's 2.5 interpreter is used to execute it.
I've already changed environment path order, putting subversion's last.
Now when I run python from command line, the 2.7 is run, but when I pass the script's filename, version 2.5 seems to be running it, as a few exceptions reveal the path.

So specifically, python 2.7 tries to imports module from subversions path.

Answer (score 2):

[PYTHONHOME](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) was set to Subversion's python path. 
System Properties>Advanced tab>Environment Variables
System Variables
Delete entry.

I don't know yet if this causes problems for subversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with `PATH` in windows, set the one you want to use at the start of the path variable. Plus, you might want to use User variables instead of system ones.

But I don't know if that answers your question because you didn't really ask anything.